# Facebook PHP SDK - Event Guestlist - Attending and Posts to PDF

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, pdf, widget

I'm looking to create a widget which will be shown in the backend of a clients website that allows them to download the guestlist of an event as a PDF file.

The user would do this by either by clicking on an event title in a list of events created by a page or by entering an event ID.

The PDF file would need to contain all posts and comments (with their nested comments) on the wall of that event as well as the people who are listed as attending.

Does anybody know if this is possible before attempting it?

I've taken a quick look at the Facebook API using the PHP SDK and I'm not sure if it's possible.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks.

## Update:

Thanks luschn! Pointed me in the perfect direction.

It is possible but I've hit a bug in development now.

Below is the code I'm using to pull the required information from an example Facebook event with the ID `1441522292797421` and display it as a list on a page.

It allows me to login and verify the app then redirects back to the page and outputs the error `**Fatal error: Call to a member function asArray() on a non-object in /home/demddlsx/public_html/index.php on line 75**` with the option to logout.

I guess I'm pulling the information incorrectly.

Can you offer any advice?

Code Below:

```
<?php 
$guestlist = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/1441522292797421/feed' ))->execute()->getGraphObject();
$poster_name = $guestlist->getProperty('name');
$poster_comment =  $guestlist->getProperty('message');
$posters = $poster_name->asArray();
$comments = $poster_name->asArray();
?>
<h2>Event Comments</h2>
<ul>
<?php 
foreach($posters as $poster){ 
echo '<li>' . $poster . '</li>';
}
?>
</ul>
<ul>
<?php 
foreach($comments as $comment){ 
echo '<li>' . $comment . '</li>';
}
?>
</ul>
<?php 

$attending = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET','/1441522292797421/attending' ))->execute()->getGraphObject();
$attendee = $attending->getProperty('name');
$names = $attendee->asArray();
?>
<h2>Event Attendees</h2>
<ul>
<?php 
foreach($names as $name){ 
echo '<li>' . $name . '</li>';
}
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: check "$attending" with var_dump - seems that $attendee is empty

Comment: Thanks again @luschn got it all working now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily get the guest list: http://www.devils-heaven.com/guest-list-of-facebook-events/

API Call: `/[EVENT-ID]/attending`

The Facebook docs tell you exactly what you can do with the Event Feed and what permissions you need: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/event/feed

> A user access token with user_events permission is required.

You could try with an App or Page Access Token too, if it´s a Page Event.

More information about Access Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/